# Excel VBA Vlookup issue

Tags: excel, ssis, vba

I'm a complete beginner to Excel VBA.

The following is code I've written that should iterate through a column in a sheet, filling values by referring to the column value to it's left and referring to another sheet in the same workbook to find what the correct corresponding value should be.

I've used a `While` loop so i can apply this `VLOOKUP` macro to each cell in the column ( only the lookup value, changes, which should be a variable denoting the column to the left) :

```
Dim result As String
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim rownum As Integer
Dim iterator As Integer
Dim lookup_value As String
Dim vlookupString1 As String

Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("datasheet")
rownum = sheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Set iterator = 3

While iterator < rownum

lookup = "M" & iterator
vlookup1String = "=VLOOKUP(" & lookup & ",'GICS Sub-industry codes'!$A$2:$B$155,2,FALSE)"
With ActiveSheet.Cells
       Range("N" & iterator).Select
       Selection.Value = vlookup1String
End With
iterator = iterator + 1

End While
```

I'm getting an error @ end while saying "expected if or select or sub..."

1) Have i made a syntax error?
2) Is my approach correct. I have observed this string approach to designing `VLOOKUPS` in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) only in one other place. It seemed best suited.

Comment: Selection.Value = vlookup1String Should probably be Selection.Formula = vlookup1String

Comment: Also I don't think your With ActiveSheet.Cells is doing anything, you can probably take it out.

Comment: First of all, make sure that the sheet name is not too long and avoid spaces when working with VBA code. Also, try Selection.Formula

Comment: Use `WEND` instead of `END WHILE`

Comment: Just a few thoughts: `iterator` is an Integer so you do not use `Set` when assigning it, just use `iterator = 3`. Also, several of your variables are either not declared or are misspelled. Use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code to correct these kinds of errors even before running the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fixing your code**
You should use `Wend` not `End While` for your loop.

**Cleaner Alternative**
But you can fill an entire range in a single shot as below

1. It is better to "loop up" a range from the bottom using `End(xlup)` than to look down with `End(xlDown)` (which relies on no spaces)
2. You almost never need to use `Select` in VBA

*Further explanation*

1. `rng1` sets a working range from the last used cell in column A in sheet  *datasheet* to A3
2. `rng1.Offset(0, Range("N1").Column - 1)` says offset rng1 (which is column A) by 13 columns to use column N (ie OFFSET A by 14-1) for the formula insertion
3. I used the macro recorder to get the code you needed in column N for this part `"=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'GICS Sub-industry codes'!R2C1:R155C2,2,FALSE)"`.
4. IN `R1C1` speak, `RC[-1]` means refer to the cell in the same row, but one column to the left. So in `N3`, the formula will start as `=VLOOKUP(M4..)`, So in `N30`, the formula will start as `=VLOOKUP(M30..) etc

**Suggested code**

```
Sub QuickFill()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Set ws = Sheets("datasheet")
Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.[a3], ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
rng1.Offset(0, Range("N1").Column - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'GICS Sub-industry codes'!R2C1:R155C2,2,FALSE)"
End Sub
```

Comment: can you explain your code as well? I can't fully understand it. Especially what exactly Offset does. I have several such vlookups i need to create for about 4-5 other columns on my datasheet so I'll need to reproduce the same. Thanks :)

Comment: the value of a cell in column N of the "datasheet" worksheet is obtained by looking up the value of the cell in column M, searching for it in column A of the "GICS.." sheet, and getting the corresponding value in column B for that row... Is that what your logic is doing now?

Comment: @user1638796 I have added further detail. Hope that helps

Comment: thanks a ton.. the code's working well! been hunting around for a useful explanation for the past 2 days on how to effectively use macros in vba! :) big props!